# raise remedy ticket using windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, remedy

Is there any solution available to create ticket in BMC remedy via windows batch file? When googled I got [this](http://thwack.solarwinds.com/message/94948), but I could not find any website that gives installer for esp_createentry.exe Anyone knows the website which allows to download esp_createentry.exe?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is by sending an email with a vb script called by your batch file:

BMC Remedy Action Request System 7.6.04 BMC Remedy Email Engine Guide:

https://docs.bmc.com/docs/download/attachments/165478929/ARS_EmailEngineGuide_7604.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1348734940000&api=v2

This thread has a brief overview:
https://communities.bmc.com/thread/68452

VBScript to send email:
http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm

Comment: OOps! The first URL redirects me to invalid access page, even after login.

Comment: I edited the remedy link in my answer, and also provided another link with supporting information. Did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using ARSperl or Java for creating the ticket. Just push an entry to HPD:IncidentInterface-Create